# Google Assistant SDK TypeError

Tags: model, get

When I run

```
googlesamples-assistant-devicetool get --model civicradiopiproject
```

to start the google assistant it comes up with the type error of
  `TypeError: 'flush' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`
 I then went to the file and did sudo nano hotword.py, this is the code in the file that comes up with the error

```
print('Registering....', end='', flush=True)
```

Why does the command return that error? I myself have tried editing the files and still no luck. Could someone help?

Answer (score 2):

The flush arg is a python 3 feature. future import should backport the feature...

[Here is a link to the backport](https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/issues/143)

It also wasn't working for me.

For now you can go edit the file.

```
/home/pi/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/googlesamples/assistant/library/hotword.py
```

and change the print line to

```
print('Registering....')
```

I'm sure google will update their sample to cater for this.